# Enable Twilio SIP Metadata in Twilio Voice Request

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Do anyone know how to enable SIP metadata in the Twilio Voice Request (per this documentation: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request)?

We send calls to Twilio numbers via Elastic SIP Trunking.  We want to use SIP metadata in the Twilio Request to route calls using Twiml.  Ultimately we'll do this with an external partner, but we're testing right now with our own numbers in Twilio.

The motivation is that with a direct SIP connect, we can ensure an external carrier does not strip our SIP X-Headers, which is the information we want to pass.

Here's the scenario in a bit more detail:

- NumberOurs (number outside of Twilio we own)
- NumberTwilio (twilio number we bought on their stack)
- NumberTwilio is configured with the twilio voice request
- we receive a call on NumberOurs
- we sip-connect to our elastic twilio trunk, sending to NumberTwilio@us...twilio.com, with additional SIP X-Headers

Expected: The call logs will show a twilio voice request showing the additional Sip* parameters in the request.  The documentation suggests these are present for SIP calls.

Actual: The call logs doesn't have the Sip* parameters.

I've verified the Sip Invite in our elastic trunk logs show we're sending via that pathway.  Working backwards, I can't figure out when the Sip* data is supposed to be enabled, so I could work backwards in our configuration.  Is there a SIP-only entity, similar to a phone number, which we're supposed to use in this scenario?

Thanks in advance for any help!
Rich

Answer (score 1):

Twilio support gave me a call to help me resolve my configuration issue.  H/T Rob and Cara at Twilio.

Twilio Voice Requests only include Sip parameters if they come through a SIP Domain.  We were using SIP Elastic Trunk, which doesn't provide those details.  As well, Sip parameters aren't passed across accounts.  It's obvious in the configuration/implementation, but worth noting.

To get this to work, we'll have our partner set up a Twilio SIP Domain on their account.  They will whitelist our IP's, give us credentials, and we can send SIP to that domain; much the same as we do with Elastic Trunk (at the SIP/networking layer, anyway).

Our partner will then configure a URL of their choosing to return Twiml when the SIP Invite is received.  They can use the X-Header we provide to determine what to do with the request.

What's cool about this is that you shouldn't need actual numbers, which saves you the monthly charges.  As well, traffic flowing in via SIP roughly half the cost per minute.